# InfoPath library throws NotImplementedException for XmlFormView.XmlForm.SaveAs method

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, infopath, xmlformview

I'm using the XmlFormView in a SharePoint page to view InfoPath browser enabled forms and programmatically add some opening and saving logic.

All goes fine, without the [XmlForm.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.xmlform.saveas%28v=Office.12%29.aspx) method. This method throws an NotImplementedException if I call it on an instantiated XmlForm and with a valid location, see code:

ASPX:

```
<InfoPath:XmlFormView ID="infoPathFormView" ShowHeader="false" Style="width: 100%;" runat="server" />
```

Code behind:

```
infoPathFormView.SaveLocation = "http://localhost/MyFormLibrary";
infoPathFormView.DataBind();

if(infoPathFormView.XmlForm.New)
{
   string fileName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
   infoPathFormView.XmlForm.SaveAs(fileName); // This line throws.
}
else
{
   infoPathFormView.XmlForm.Save();
}
```

Resulting in the following exception and stacktrace:

> The method or operation is not
>   implemented.   at
>   Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.DocumentLifetime.XmlFormHost.SaveAs(String
>   fileUrl)     at
>   MyProject.ShowInfoPathForm.SaveButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArguments)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData)     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

For clarity, I found that Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.DocumentLifetime.XmlFormHost is an internal class that inherits from the abstract [XmlForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942970%28v=Office.12%29.aspx) class.

- Does anyone have an idea why this piece of code is throwing a NotImplementedException?
- Is there a workaround to be able to save the XmlForm with the specified filename?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, the XsnLocation, XmlLocation, and **SaveLocation** properties of the XmlFormView control must specify locations in the same site collection as the custom page.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the SaveAs is not available for server forms as specified in the article you linked from the question: "This type or member can be accessed only from code running in forms opened in Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007."

Consider using SaveLocation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.server.controls.xmlformview.savelocation.aspx) to specify file name in the same site collection as the template.